# Regex diacritics

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
String regExpression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+,. '-]{1,"+maxCharacters+"}$";
```

which works fine for me, except, it doesn't allow any UTF-8 diacritics in it(Ă ă Â â Î î Ș ș Ț ț).

I only need my current regex to accept diacritics in it besides what it already does.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look into the [POSIX character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to catch those. Sadly Java Regex don't support language specific POSIX classes but maybe
`\p{Graph}  A visible character:   [\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]` or
`\p{Print}  A printable character: [\p{Graph}\x20]`
will fit.

Best fit as suggested by Sorin probably is `\p{L}` (Letter).

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regexer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxCharacters = 100;
        String data = "Ă ă Â â Î î Ș ș Ț ț";
        String pattern = "^[\\p{L}0-9+,. '-]{1," + maxCharacters + "}$";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        if (p.matcher(data).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Hit");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }

    }
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Or, even better, [\p{L}] which means letter.

Comment: Hm.. I tried with \p{L} and it still didn't work. The only thing that worked so far is "^[\\wĂăÂâÎîȘșȚț0-9+,. '-]{1,"+maxCharacters+"}$" but I don't know how ok this is . Thoughts on this ?